# Can bootstrap mix with defined CSS?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I wish take the advantage of bootstrap for making some columns (by use of predefined classes like .col-sm-), but also to include additional widths for smaller phones. The point is that Netbeans gives a message "class not found" (for each one, as moverover it), so I am not sure whether only some of them are actually OK. As said, on Chrome as well on a few available devices, looks fine.
Thank you in advance for any clarification!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html lang="en">  
...  
<meta charset="utf-8">  
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/mycss.css">  
    ...  

    <div class="row"  style="background-color: greenyellow; color: crimson">  
        <div class="col-xxxs-2 col-xxs-2 col-xs-2 col-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 ">  
        </div>  
    </div>  
</html>
```

In css it is defined like follows 
    @media only screen and (max-width: 328px){
         .col-xxxs-1 {width: 8.33%;}
         ....
     }

Comment: So you are creating your own css classes like `col-xss-*`? and some of those work and some don't?

Comment: Yes, I created my own css classes, but I am I wundering whether they work correct (given the slight difference) or by definition might not be allowed to be mixed, as a supposed conflict from bootstrap. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while, I got how much easy would have been the answer. Probably the reason for not so many answers/comments. I removed from

```
<div class="col-xxxs-2 col-xxs-2 col-xs-2 col-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 ">
```

all classes related to bootstrap, except the last one, i.e. *col-lg-2*. Since it works still fine on all smaller devices, there is no reason to see a conflict between  bootstrap classes and the user defined ones.

Therefore, no ground to keep it longer open. 
It remain the *fake messages from Netbeans*, e.g. "class col-... not found", as mouse goes over those classes from the above line of HTML file (see the attached picture). Finally this message can be removed by including one more link to the boosstrap library, although with no relevant benefit.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css"/>
```

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the -1! If left the answer not updated & without additional clarifications, eventually useful for others, was just OK. This is the risk to try get involved and improve in a way.